# Trying to change a label text in Kivy, and it never changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Here is a basic sample that I am working with.  The label displays as I would expect, but **the text never changes**, even though I do see the print statements in the console showing that the Clock.schedule_interval is *ticking* away.   Any thoughts as to what have gone wrong???

Thank you and Happy New Year!

First the .kvlang file

```
<Demo>:
    button_text: my_button
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: my_button
            text: 'Initial Text!'
```

And my Python.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random



class Demo(BoxLayout):
    button_text = ObjectProperty

    def change_text(self, dt):
        self.button_text.text = str(random.randint(1, 10))
        print('Should have changed button text to {}'.format(self.button_text.text))

    def start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.change_text, 10)

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        foo = Demo()
        foo.start()
        return Demo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing parenthesis

```
button_text = ObjectProperty
```

change to

```
button_text = ObjectProperty(None) # Ha! :)
```

Also you should return **foo** and not create another **Demo**

```
def build(self):
    foo = Demo()
    foo.start()
    #return Demo() change to...
    return foo
```

Since the later **Demo** will not be updated...

Comment: And right you are:)  Silly to miss the object creation in the beginning!  Thanks for the help